# The pictures on Privileges help page are outdated

Tags: bug, help-center

There are plenty of pictures showing how to use the privilege tools, [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges). They seem to be outdated. For example, the picture about [offering a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), shown below,  compared with the actual one, also shown below:

**Help page**

[image]

**Actual one**

[image]

I'm sure there are plenty of more pressing things to do, but I just thought it was useful to point this out.